# Switch module test circuit design

Tags: arduino, voltage, led, batteries, power-electronics

I am doing a project to make a test box that would test the switch module in the photo below. Please see circuit diagram below for inside of the switch. Please note this switch is not an ordinary switch has it resistors inside which is more complex.

So far I have designed the test box circuit using various way and methods  I have used  555 timer circuit, Transistor and finally using NAND logic gate. The best option was the last one using NAND Logic gate as it worked the way I wanted by using a 10k resistor and 3 LEDs using the truth table however due to my switch circuit on the inside this would not work.

```
A B  Output 
0 0   1
0 1   1
1 0   1
1 1   0
```

This NAND gate logic worked on circuit simulation tool after using two ordinary switches. However, when I try to integrate my tester box switch to the switch I have noticed my switch is much more complex has its got a circuit inside with resistors which I couldn't integrate the two circuits.

The only other idea I have is to do this using Arduino and program it maybe.
Can anyone tell me ways to do this, as I have run out of ideas now?

[image] Reference A

[image] **Reference B**

[image] **Reference C**

[image] **Reference D**

PS:

@jonk Apologies for misclarification yes the buttons are momentary and no it's not latching magnet motion. Also, its not random switch its got circuit inside which indicated above, my goal is just to test the switch if there are connected or not and their state by showing me LEDs to indicate that. ''wanting to push those buttons to verify they work correctly?'' Yes I want to verify if they work and connected

Response to @Transistor's comments:

1. *Is someone is going to connect the switch module, press the buttons in all four NAND combinations and watch the LEDs?* - Yes, the switch is going to be connected with the NAND circuit and watch the LEDs if they are connected and works.
2. *Does the test circuit need to confirm the presence of the four resistors?* - yes, the resistor circuit should confirm the four resistors including the switches, In fact, it should configure the switch circuit diagram and it should work by simulating and integrating with NAND gate (tester box circuit).
3. *Does the test circuit need to check the values of the four resistors?*  - Yes, it should.
4. *Your simulation doesn't show the four internal resistors. Why not?*  - The four resistor from my switch circuit diagram has not been simulated yet - the simulation circuit above is my tester box circuit and however the 2nd image is the switch circuit from the supplier datasheet.
5. *Why do you require a NAND?* - This NAND logic works well to what output I want to achieve, I want the output to be on what input is inserted. If any other circuit suggestion do please let me know.

Another Response to @Transistor's comments:

Sorry, I think I have confused you and you have misunderstood my question. Now I have reference each image clearly i.e (References A-C). So the switch unit in Ref A is what I am trying to test, the switch unit has got an onboard installed circuit to see Ref B, Also please note that REF B circuit diagram is already been given by the supplier. In other words, Ref A&B are equivalent. As you can see from the circuit diagram REF B that which doesn't have or contain any a power supply at all. So Ref C is just a draft circuit that I was hoping it would work and I could able to test switch unit in Reference A;- by connecting REf B to the REf  C (the circuit I have created ) to test the switch unit REF A.
So just to sum up and answer your question ''What two circuits? '' One circuit is Ref A and other  REF C. Also this Ref A switch unit is much more complex to test since its got 4 resistors inside and 3 pins see an image and its not just an ordinary simple switch(Reference D)

Comment: I don't think I fully apprehend your goals. I don't see a datasheet listed and it's not clear to me if those buttons are momentary, or not. (Reeds often are. But it is possible to mechanically arrange latching magnet motion, too. So I don't know.) Are you taking random switches and just "testing their state?" (Which would imply they are mechanically latching to me.) Or are you wanting to push those buttons to verify they work correctly? Or? It's possible I'm not even close, too. So could you expand a little on the goals?

Comment: I have fixed the formatting and some other details in your question. Please edit your question to explain: (1) Is someone is going to connect the switch module, press the buttons in all four NAND combinations and watch the LEDs? (2) Does the test circuit need to confirm the presence of the four resistors? (3) Does the test circuit need to check the *values* of the four resistors? (4) Your simulation doesn't show the four internal resistors. Why not? (5) Why do you require a NAND? Why can't you watch the output of pins 1 and 2? Put all the information into your question and not in the comments.

Comment: @jonk Apologies for misclarification  yes the buttons are momentary and no its not latching magnet motion. Also its not random switch its got circuit inside which indicated above, my goal is just to test the switch if there are connected or not and their state by showing me LEDs to indicate that. ''wanting to push those buttons to verify they work correctly?'' Yes I want to verify if they work and connected.

Comment: @(1)Transistor Is someone is going to connect the switch module, press the buttons in all four NAND combinations and watch the LEDs?  - Yes the switch is going to be connected with the NAND circuit and watch the LEDs if they are connected and works. (2) Does the test circuit need to confirm the presence of the four resistors? - yes  the resistor circuit should confirm the four resistors including the switches, In fact it should configure the switch circuit diagram and it should work by simulating and integrating with NAND gate (tester box circuit). Please see the rest answers on the question

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpxplZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simple test fixture.*

This simple test fixture might suffice.

Switch testing:

- With SW1 off about 2.5 mA will flow through D1 lighting it dimly.
- With SW1 on about 13 mA will flow through D1 lighting it brightly.
- With SW2 off about 2.5 mA will flow through D2 lighting it dimly.
- With SW2 on about 10 mA will flow through D2 lighting it brightly.

Resistor testing:

- If R1 or R3 is missing the dim test will fail.
- If R2 or R4 is missing the respective LED will never light.

Comment: Thank you so much for your circuit really helpful, however I am not so sure how you would connect the above simple circuit you created into the test box circuit i.e the NAND gate circuit that i have created with 3 LED outputs to verify if each switch's are connected  and the state LED output I am after is  when its not connected the LED is OFF and When its connected the LED is ON . IF you think that circuit above (Nand gate) will not work with the Figure (Figure 1. A simple test fixture) then please provide an alterntive circuit so it works out when the two circuits are connected to my testbox

Comment: Forget the NAND circuit. Just plug the switch unit into the circuit above and watch the two LEDs as you press the buttons. If you have some other requirement then it is not clear. "*... when the two circuits are connected to my testbox.*" What two circuits? There is only one circuit in each switch assembly.

Comment: Do you have email I can send you documents and circuit diagram and  clarify the question clearly as I have limited word here

Comment: Certainly not. All discussion should be done on EE.SE. I'm not aware of any limit to the text you can add to your question. You are limited to the number of inline images until you get enough reputation. If you upload them someone will inline them for you.

Comment: Sorry I think I have confused your misunderstood my question. So  now I have reference each image clearly i.e (References A-C). So the switch unit in Ref A is what I am trying to test, the switch unit has got a on-board installed circuit see Ref B, in other words they are Ref A&B are equivalent.  As you can see from the circuit diagram REF B that which doesn't not have or contain any a power supply at all. Also please note that REF B circuit diagram is already been given by the supplier. *See above in details

Comment: OK. Your problem is that you have to test many of these switch units. Your operator has to insert the switch unit into a test fixture and verify that the buttons work and that the resistors are present. My circuit which uses two LEDs and a 5 V power supply (a phone charger) will do this for you.

Comment: What is your circuit to put inside the test box so the operator can test the switch

Comment: As I will need the 3 LEDs on the test box. One to show if its connected properly, The other two LEDs will be used for the top and bottom (see reference A) switch unit when its close and open, in another word if the push buttons working or not

Comment: You only need the two LEDs. Read my answer again. It shows the output conditions when the unit under test is connected and when each button is pressed. (1) Insert switch module to be tested. (2) Confirm both LEDs light dimly. (3) Press left button. Left LED lights brightly. (4) Press right button. Right LED lights brightly. (5) Pass.

Comment: (2) Confirm both LEDs light dimly?, , - your circuit above on simulation tool I tested it and both LEDs doesn't light dimly when inserted this is because the switch unit is  normally open, it only lightly dims when one of them is pressed.

Comment: Try it will real LEDs. I have calculated the LED currents through the resistors in my answer and they are high enough to light any indicator LED dimly - especially the high-efficiency type. Use a USB phone charger for a power-supply and cut the 'B' plug off an old USB lead. Red = +. Black = -. Two indicator LEDs and you can try it out.

Comment: To be honest I can not have the colour to stay the same and dim, for my project the requirement is to have either ON/off or  alternative to change colour the LED to different colours.